# Checkboxes behind a div turned visible when their opacity is changed

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I just found a very strange HTML behaviour: a checkbox normally hidden behind another element (like a div) becomes visible if its opacity or the opacity of its container is set below 1.

Here is the basic setup, we have a set of checkboxes behind a grey div:

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Baz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBaz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As expected, you cannot see the checkboxes. But if we change their opacity or the opacity of their containers, they do become visible:

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 0.5">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Baz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 0.5">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBaz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course we can avoid this by setting the `z-index` of the grey div:

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 0.5">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Baz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 0.5">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBaz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, the solution is obvious, but nevertheless I still have a question: why did that happen in the first place? What's the reason for the difference between the first and second snippets?

By the way, as I mentioned in the first paragraph, it's worth mentioning that the checkbox keeps hidden if the opacity is set to 1:

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Foo</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Baz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity: 1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>FooBaz</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position: absolute is given to tooltip class so it is overlapping checkbox so you have to manage with z-index. Its not strange it happen becuase checkbox dont have position absolute and tooltip has   position absolute so it is overlapping

Comment: Well... you can see stuff through transparent things, but you can't see stuff through opaque things. What's the problem here?

You can see stuff through glass, but not through a wall, because the glass is transparent.

Comment: @TorNato if you set the opacity of the div to 1 you cannot see it, but if you set it to 0.9 you can see it. It's exactly the opposite of what you said.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the duplicate targets, the second one (*Stacking order of elements affected by opacity*) is exactly my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because `opacity` causes a new [stacking context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#det-stacking-context). This can also happen with the following CSS properties:

- [`opacity`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#opacity)
- [CSS Transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/)
- [Filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/)
- [CSS Regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/)
- [Paged Media](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/)

> **Rule 8.2:** All opacity descendants with opacity less than 1, in tree order, create a stacking context generated atomically.

```css
.checkboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tooltip"></div><!-- own stack context and above the other elements -->
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="checkbox" style="opacity:0.5"><!-- own stack context and later on the painting order than position -->
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span>Bar</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the stacking order, thanks for your answer. However, setting the opacity to 1 keeps the element hidden, while setting it to 0.99 or any other value displays it (please check the edit in my question). That's the behaviour I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Now I have an answer (rule 8.2). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what happened I have to simplify your example much more :

```css
.checkbox{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <span>Foo</span>
  </div>
```

Now it looks not related to checkbox any more. It just how position elements works :

according to your document flow The `.checkbox` element comes after `.checkbox` what means a higher position for `.checkbox`

why? because you didn't set `z-index` property for `.tooltip` what means z-index still `auto` . and the value of auto does not establish a new local stacking context

see the MDN about z-index auto [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

so to resolve this whiteout using z-index :

- you need to move the div you want to be at the top at the end and use `top:0`

```css
.checkbox{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="checkbox">
    <span>Foo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
```

- or using z-index as you mentioned with positive value to create a new local stacking context